# SSIS Dynamics CRM to Dynamics AX Integration

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, kingswaysoft

We are currently working on the integration between Dynamics AX to Dynamics CRM and viceversa.

In the direction of Ax to CRM, we have SQL queries which joins multiple AX tables and using the result of the JOINS query we are able to map all fields to CRM from AX.

While working on the other direction CRM to AX, we have to update multiple tables on AX based on single entity for example Account on CRM. But the Dynamics AX Destination component is showing only one table to update.

Can some has some idea how to deal this other way integration from CRM to AX when we have to update multiple tables in the AX system?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exact technology you're using for the AX entity? Is it DIXF/DMF, AIF, etc? When you say "one table", are you sure you're not viewing a **denormalized** data entity, which is actually composed of multiple tables?

Comment: Thank you Alex. We are using SSIS kingsway software for the integration of dynamics AX to dynamics CRM 365.                                       
From AX to CRM we have a sql query with many joins between different tables and we use this query and fetch all fields and map them to CRM.                            
We should also perform the integration from CRM to AX so we will have source for example Accounts from CRM and we should map these fields to different AX tables

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SSIS to load data into AX's SQL database directly!

You'd be bypassing the entire AX stack of business logic some of which is vital to the proper functioning of the system.

Ideally you wouldn't use direct SQL going the other way either, but you're at least unlikely to cause data loss in that direction.  The issues there are just table locking, performance, and future-proofing.

There are a number of ways to handle the CRM > AX, all of which are quite likely to require X++ development.  Again, do not ever call insert or update in sql for ax's databases.

The comments mention DIXF, AIF, and DMF as possible ways to build this.  You can also just write an AX batch job if it does not need to be triggered from the outside.  If D365 CRM has a REST api, an AX batch job should be able to consume it and then properly upsert the ax data properly from within the AX stack.  If not, you may need to shunt this CRM data to a holding database and then consume it from within AX.

The exact mechanics of such a connector though are well outside the scope of a single answer, but the crux is this must be done within AX.  You cannot simply write data to the AX database.